# Scroll down to certain place programmatically in ScrollView with multiple Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, scrollview

I use a `ScrollView` with multiple `Fragments` which are placed at runtime.
Now if I press a `Button` in a fragment, I want to scroll down to the bottom of the 
respective fragment, not to the bottom of the whole `scrollview`.
There is always a button at the bottom of the fragment, maybe it is possible to trigger the button as item for "scrollTo..".
Any proposals how to do this?

This is the ScrollView

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

        ...

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is what one Fragment would look like

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        ...

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">

        ...

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:text="@string/continueBtn"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:text="@string/backBtn"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use scrollToPosition()

Comment: but how can I call the ScrollView from the fragment?

Comment: @WeSt can you post your code ?

Comment: @Sushrita I added a part of the code

Answer (score 1):

I would use instead of a `ScrollView`, a `RecyclerView` and each list element would be each of your fragments. Then in order to move to each one I would use the `scrollToPosition()` method.

Comment: But the Fragments are not always on the same place. sometimes one Fragment can be the first item at the top and sometimes somewhere at the end. But I need this scrollable problem just for one certain fragment

Comment: That's not should be a problem. Even if this changed in runtime you could use `notifyDatasetChanged()` so your recyclerview has always the most updated "sequence" of your fragments, if I understand correctly what your objection is. On the other hand and still using a scrollview, maybe you could  measure the height of each fragment and scroll an absolute value of pixels. I haven't implemented something like this but I think it might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my problem:

```
scrl.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            scrl.smoothScrollBy(0,btn.getBottom());
        }
    });
```

What I need was `scrollBy` not `scrollTo`.